# Assembly. How to return a value from function using stack?

Tags: assembly, stack, 64-bit, att

I'm creating a programm that is suppose to get an index of numerical sequence and return the value of number of this index. Sequence is recursive. My question is:

How do I return a value from a function, that is calculating the answer? I did it using registers only, then I did it using stack for passing parameters and register (rax) to return value. And now I have to use stack for passing parameters and returning the value. I don't know how to set up the whole frame before "ret" and then how to get the answer after getting back to home adress (next line after "call function").

My not working version of code with passing parameters by stack and returning value by stack (please skip the comments in my foreign language):

```
#   przez stos
.section .data
# x_i = 3*x_(i-1) - 2*x_(i-2),    x_0 = 5, x_1 = 2
.section .bss
.comm text, 512
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:

push $4         # zadany indeks

push $5         # wczesniejsza wartosc
push $2         # pozniejsza wartosc

call znajdz
break2:
pop %rax
add $24, %rsp
break3: 
wynik_rax:
mov %rax, %rdi
mov $60, %rax
syscall

.type znajdz, @function
znajdz:              
push %rbp
mov %rsp, %rbp
sub $8, %rsp
mov 16(%rbp), %r9   # %r9 - pozniejszy wyraz
mov 24(%rbp), %r8   # %r8 - wczesniejszy wyraz
mov 32(%rbp), %rdx  # %rdx - indeks
cmp $0, %rdx        
je zerowy_indeks
cmp $1, %rdx
je pierwszy_indeks
mov %r9, %r10       # zapisanie kopii pozniejszego wyrazu w %r10
mov %r9, %rax 
mov $3, %rdi  
push %rdx 
imul %rdi
mov %rax, %rbx
mov %r8, %rax
mov $-2, %rdi 
imul %rdi
pop %rdx
add %rax, %rbx     
mov %rbx, %r9       # %r9 - wyliczona wartosc
mov %r10, %r8       # %r8 - wartosc wczesniejszego wyrazu

dec %rdx
cmp $1, %rdx
je koniec
push %rdx
push %r8
push %r9
call znajdz ###
add $24, %rsp
jmp koniec

zerowy_indeks:
mov $5, %rax
jmp koniec

pierwszy_indeks:
mov $2, %rax
jmp koniec

koniec: ##### quitting the function, the place to look after #####
# push %r9
mov %rbp, %rsp
pop %rbp
# mov %r9, %rax
push %r9
break1:
ret
```

Comment: For functions that return objects that won't fit in registers, the caller allocates space on the stack before pushing parameters, and calling the function. The function then fills in the stack area (just above the parameters) that is allocated by the caller. For Windows 64 bit API, the caller allocates 32 bytes of  space on the stack before any parameters, usually so the callee can save rcx, rdx, r8, and r9 in the caller allocated space.

Comment: I don't really know how to use this information. I'm using Ubuntu x64. Should I allocate space for the argument before every call? Like add 8 to rbp and then push the answer to stack and use "ret"?

Comment: I don't know the Unbuntu X64 API.